# Count of Instances for One Attribute Based on Several Other Attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Code       Date        Result    
1         6/1/17         A     
1         6/3/17         A     
2         6/5/17         A     
2         6/7/17         B     
1         6/1/17         A     
1         6/3/17         B     
1         6/5/17         C     
2         6/7/17         C
```

I need to write a query that picks all the distinct codes, the count of all instance of each code, then the count of each code based on result.  So final result would be:

```
Code       Total Count      Count A     Count B     Count C   
1               5              3           1           1 
2               3              1           1           1
```

Comment: Is it only A, B, and C?

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

This query may work for you:

```
SELECT
code,
COUNT(*) AS total_count,
SUM(CASE result WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_a,
SUM(CASE result WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_b,
SUM(CASE result WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_c
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY code
ORDER BY code;
```

Are there only result values of A, B and C? If so, then this would be OK. If there are more values, then writing 10 or 20 or 100 case statements would be messy and there would be another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Result` are known, you can use bbrumm's answer above. However, if there are more `Result`, you can use a dynamic crosstab:

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl(Code INT, Date Date, Result VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO Tbl VALUES
(1, '06/01/2017',   'A'),
(1, '06/03/2017',   'A'),
(2, '06/05/2017',   'A'),
(2, '06/07/2017',   'B'),
(1, '06/01/2017',   'A'),
(1, '06/03/2017',   'B'),
(1, '06/05/2017',   'C'),
(2, '06/07/2017',   'C');

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    code
    , COUNT(Result) AS TotalCount' + CHAR(10);

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , SUM(CASE WHEN Result = ''' + Result + ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME('Count' + Result) + CHAR(10)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Result FROM Tbl) t;

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM Tbl
GROUP BY Code
ORDER BY Code';

PRINT(@sql);
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

DROP TABLE Tbl;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://rextester.com/VNXNLN92478)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

you can simply PIVOT like below

```
select 
  Code, 
  [Total Count]=ISNULL(A,0)+ISNULL(B,0)+ISNULL(C,0),
  [Count A]=ISNULL(A,0),
  [Count B]=ISNULL(B,0),
  [Count C]=ISNULL(C,0)
from
(select * from T)src
pivot
( count(Date) for Result in (A,B,C))p
```

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/VNNI99939)**</kbd>